# command to download profile image - yowsup 2.0 python whatsapp

Tags: python, whatsapp, yowsup

I have a problem with yowsup 2.0 and python.

What is the command to download a profile image (of a friend) using yowsup 2.0 + python?

Should I use a layer?

Comment: Sorry but no option is available I guess in This regard, you should try registering this as a issue on Github page, The developer is highly active these days :)